# How to remove the Y-axis labels, ticks and axis label in a plot created using librosa.display.specshow

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, data-visualization, librosa

I am using this code to visualize the melspectogram and save the image

```
spec = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=y,sr=sr,n_mels=128 )
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
spec = librosa.amplitude_to_db(spec, ref=np.max)
librosa.display.specshow(spec, sr=sr, y_coords=None,y_axis='log',fmax=20000)
plt.savefig('spectogram.png')
```

[image: Click here to view the melspectogram]

I am unable to remove the Y-axis labels, ticks, and the label of the axis and save them.

Comment: `ax.set_yticklabels([])`

Comment: @Parth Shah I am getting this error: NameError: name 'ax' is not defined

Comment: If you do not want to retrieve the axis `ax`, use `plt.yticks([])`.

Comment: It works! but the ticks are still visible and there still is a label "Hz". https://ibb.co/KmWL533

Comment: Do you not want the axis label? Do you not want the ticks? Edit the question with these details and I will post an answer.

Comment: Does this work? `plt.axis('off')`

Comment: I have added an answer. Please upvote and accept. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable the axis all together with:

```
plt.axis('off')
```